# Hyperledger fabric delete compositekey not deleted

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am using the most recent Fabric (1.1?)  I have question regarding deleting composite key, this is what I did:

1) Use CreateCompositeKey to create a key

2) call PutState the key

3) call GetStateByPartialCompositeKey for that key and do find the key

4) Call DelState on that found key

5) call GetStateByPartialCompositeKey to see if the key were deleted but was surprisingly still found the key

Any idea?  Was it because simply finding the key is not good enough and I need to do a 'GetState' to see if the key still exists?

Comment: The most recent fabric is 1.2, not 1.1

Did you do this in different transactions and ensured they all got successfully committed without any MVCC conflicts?

Comment: yes I did, all transactions return success (then I guess mine us 1.1)

Comment: what database are you using? golevelDB or couchDB? can you reproduce this on a docker-compose environment?

Comment: Are you using Hyperledger Composer?  - If so you need to stick on Fabric 1.1 at the moment.

Comment: I believe this is couchdb, I thought composite key only apply to couch db, right?  Yes it is fabric 1.1

Answer (score 0):

On Fabric 2.2, you can delete a composite key like this:

```js
const indexToDelete = await ctx.stub.createCompositeKey('attribute1~attribute2', [var1, var2]);
await ctx.stub.putState(indexToDelete, null);
```